# How to build CM system app without odex?

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

When I build CM7 's system app (eg. ADWLauncher) , I switch to ADWLauncher's folder and run "mm" command, then I get .apk and .odex file, How can I just get .apk file with dex in it. I mean should I change somewhere in Android.mk or generic.mk to let the compilation just result apk file which can instsall directly.

Comment: And how did you do this?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer too...

Answer (score 3):

Try this `mm WITH_DEXPREOPT=false -B`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [backsmali](https://code.google.com/p/smali/wiki/DeodexInstructions) which can combine odex and apk  files

```
baksmali -a [api_level] -x [odex_file] -d [framework_dir]
```

Or change the WITH_DEXPREOPT environment variable in

```
build/target/board/generic/BoardConfig.mk
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens (at least to me) when I have not declared a device I'm building for with `breakfast`.  For example, without running `breakfast hammerhead`, I got `Dialer.apk` and `arm/Dialer.odex` in the output directory.  Furthermore, the device refused to run the binary, even after putting the `.odex` file in place.

Running `breakfast` first causes `make` to generate a single proper `Dialer.apk` that installs cleanly (using `adb root`/`remount`/`push`) on my device.